# SharePoint 2013 Analytics and Licensing

Tags: 2013, web-analytics, licensing

I am trying to determine whether or not the SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics API can be used in an environment where all users have SPS 2013 Standard CALs. More specifically, I want to use the Microsoft.Office.Server.WebAnalytics.Reporting.AnalyticsReportFunction class to obtain information about the popularity of documents in a site.

According to http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/, the "Analytics Platform" is not available to Standard users. I'm just not sure if that includes the API.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question. If you look at the Microsoft Product User rights, they only call out "Custom Analytics Reports", so if you have access to the API/Data and create your own reports, it seems like that would be ok.

This would be similar to how auditing was used back on WSS, it was available but there was no out of the box way to view them, you had to create a custom solution to display the date in the format you wanted.

I would probably still reach out to a MS Licensing specialist.  If you want to review the PUR you can download the latest here: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/product-licensing.aspx#tab=1

Comment: I got a response from MS today, although it was from a SharePoint specialist, not a licensing specialist. His opinion is that it would not be available for use. He also thought that the API would not even be available to use with Standard edition. I haven't had a chance to verify whether or not that's true yet, but will try to remember to post back here when I do.